# PC connected over ethernet cabble cannot see Virtualbox Debian DHCP server

Tags: linux, dhcp

I am using a Debian OS on virtualbox. It has correctly configured DHCP, which works for any VM OS I run on internal network.

When I switch to bridged, and select the Realtek PCIe FE adapter (ethernet) and connect the host PC with the other PC over lan cable, ipconfig on the host computer shows the ethernet port configured in the DHCP range, but the other PC doesn't recognise a DHCP server and gets a random ip.

What would be blocking the other PC from seeing the server? Could it be something to do with the virtualbox network settings?

I have a tftp and nfs set up, to do a boot over network, which works for the VM OS. And I am trying to boot a laptop with lan connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should normally work.
I have used similar setups without any problems.

I can think of 3 possible things:

1. You are connecting both PC's with just a cable WITHOUT a switch in between.
   In that case it is possible there are some issues with establishing a proper link between the 2 which leads to DHCP requests from the 2nd PC not arriving at the VM.
2. The Realtek NIC doesn't properly handle promiscuous mode, which is needed for bridging to work properly (highly unlikely).
3. In the VM config you didn't enable the checkmark "assume cable is connected". This also sometimes gives weird effects.

If nothing helps, see if Realtek has a newer driver on the website. (Especially if you are using Windows own build-in default driver. That is not always the best driver you can use.)

Comment: Downloaded and installed the newer Realtek drivers and it worked. Thanks